# Which is the best way to implement dynamic menu in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to implement dynamic menu in Quick Launch, which should be filled by data from the database. In fact, database holds departments's names and for each department there should be separate menu item.

So the question is how to implement it in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to write a custom menu as it will give you more control/webpart.

A good example is given here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47761/Customize-QuickLaunch-Webpart